# Spring form input causes 500 server error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

**here is the jsp:**

The jsp renders without the spring form input tags being used. Don't know if that will help with identifying the issue.I believe i added the right inport for the form tags.

```
 <!-- add tag lib in order to use form tags --> 
 <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>


 <form:form action="addLogin" modelAttribute="login" >
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td>Username:</td>
 <td><form:input type="text" path="userName"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Password:</td>
 <td><form:input type="text" path="password"/></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <br>

 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form:form>
```

**Then the error:**

HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message An exception occurred processing [/WEB-INF/view/Login.jsp] at line [24]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [/WEB-INF/view/Login.jsp] at line [24]

```
21:  
22: <tr>
23: <td>Username:</td>
24:  <td><form:input type="text" path="userName"/></td>
25: </tr>
26: <tr>
27: <td>Password:</td>
```

Root Cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'login' available as request attribute
org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:153)

Could someone please tell me what is going on with the form tags that i used and why they are not working as expected.I believe this is what is causing me the error. I tried clearing cache of eclipse, re-importing the tags but nothing seemed to be succesful.

**Here is the controller method**

```
@GetMapping("/Show")
public String show(Model theModel) {
    
    theModel.addAttribute("login",new Login());
    return "Login";
}
```

Comment: show us the controller method

Comment: I updated the controller method and hope that it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the fact I added the to the model the new login method instead of creating a new login object then adding the object to the model. So when i attempt to set the parameters to pass with the form it is sending two parameters that the addLogin() is not prepared for and seems that they have not been binded to any object from the previous method.